# ID3v2 writing source for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, mp3, id3

I'm currently using ID3v1, but it has 30 characters limit for Title. So I'm forced to use ID3v2 I think.. Can someone give me proper link or library for that, cause I couldn't find it in Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID3.org has an up to date list with different implementations. Scroll to the .NET section.

https://id3.org/Implementations

Answer (score 1):

Maybe either of the following is what you're looking for:

[C# ID3 Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csid3lib/)

[ID3Sharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/id3sharp/)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [TagLib#](http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/TagLib_Sharp)

---

EDIT: the original link is broken; the project can now be found [here on Github](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp). There is also a [Nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/taglib/)

Comment: Seems like the link is broken.